# Angularjs and UI-Select: how to select an option from code

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select2, ui-select

in angularjs i have a `ui-select`:

```
<ui-select ng-model="itemSelected.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Select an item...">{{$select.selected.Name}}</ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="item in itemsList">
      <span ng-bind-html="item.Name"></span>
   </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

How can i select an item from code when i load the page?
When i load the page in the controller i get the `$scope.itemsList`: how can i select a specific item from the `controller`?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand,can u be more specific? is $scope.itemsList is an array or an object? When you load your controller,do you want to bind it with ng-model?

Comment: can you provide a sample item in your itemList?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set that on controller load itself

**Markup**

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <p>Selected: {{item.selected}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="item.selected" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a item in the list">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in items | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
      <div ng-bind-html="item.Code | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
</body>
```

**Code**

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.disabled = undefined;

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.item.selected = undefined;
  };

  $scope.item = {};
  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'Item1', Code: 'Code1', },
    { name: 'Item2', Code: 'Code3'},
    { name: 'Item3',  Code: 'Code4'},
    { name: 'Item4',  Code: 'Code4' },
    { name: 'Item5', Code: 'Code5' },
  ];

  $scope.item.selected = $scope.items[0] //here you can set the item selected
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The plunkr by @Pankaj Parkar was no longer working for the intended usage so I forked it and got it working here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6cdgJQ3YPq7Ncb3bT4A?p=preview

The key changes involved actually setting the selected item in the controller:

```
$scope.address = {};
$scope.refreshAddresses = function(address) {
    var params = {address: address, sensor: false};
    return $http.get(
    'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
    {params: params}
    ).then(function(response) {
    $scope.addresses = response.data.results
    $scope.address.selected = $scope.addresses[0];
    $scope.$apply();
    });
};
$scope.refreshAddresses('New York, NY');
```

The key addition is `$scope.address.selected = $scope.addresses[0];` and `$scope.refreshAddresses('New York, NY');` to get it to go.

I also updated the other selects to prepopulate, as well.