# angular ui select is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-select

I am using angular ui select https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select in my project. I am using `ui-select` directive

My code:

```
<select class="input-small" ng-model="dashboard.style" ng-options="f for f in ['light','hpexp']" ng-change="styleUpdated()"></select>
```

I want to use ui-select So I did,

```
<ui-select id="viewSelector"
    class="viewSelector input-small"
    ng-model="dashboard.style"
    ng-options="f for f in ['light','hpexp']" 
    ng-change="styleUpdated()"
    theme="selectize"> 
<ui-select-match placeholder="-- Select --">
   {{$select.style}}</ui-select-match>
</ui-select>
```

But it is not working. How to use `ng-options` in `ui-select`

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you add this code in fiddler?

Comment: sure.. let me try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `ui-select-choices` instead of `ng-options`. Lets try the below code, instead of yours

```
<ui-select id="viewSelector"
        class="viewSelector input-small"
        ng-model="dashboard.style"  
        ng-change="styleUpdated()"
        theme="selectize"> 
    <ui-select-match placeholder="-- Select --">
       {{$select.style}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="f for f in ['light','hpexp']">
          <div ng-bind-html="f"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

More details, please read this discussion

[Angularjs and UI-Select: how to select an option from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925943/angularjs-and-ui-select-how-to-select-an-option-from-code)

Comment: Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got 'f for f in ['light','hpexp']'.

Getting this error

Comment: Thanks, Try this `repeat="f in ['light','hpexp']"`

Comment: but on select of any option.. <ui-select-match placeholder="-- Select Style--">
            {{$select.style}}</ui-select-match>

it is not displaying anything.. if you can help it will be awesome